# PSSession display browser on remote computer

Tags: powershell, process

My goal is to display the (default) browser and open a specific URL on a remote session.

1 Create PSSession on a remote computer => OK

> $computerName = "yannTPI-1"
>
> $credential = get-credential
>
> $session = new-PSSession -computerName $computerName -credential $credential

2 Run a script => OK

> invoke-command -session $session -filePath $file

3 On that script... Open browser (many way...)

> [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("http://stackoverflow.com")
>
> start http://stackoverflow.com

And it works, under processes I can see a process corresponding to my browser. On my remote computer I'm connected with another account that the one I use to connect to it with PSSession. So it does not display as it is not the same User Name.

How can I force the display of the browser to another user ?

Sorry english is not my mother tongue, hope I'm clear enaugh.

Comment: As ravikanth says, you cannot do that. This is by design. When you are remoting, you are not starting an interactive session. PSExec is a workaround. But what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If I use Enter-PSSession instead of new-PSSession, it is then an interactive session right ? But it does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Remote interactive sessions isn't possible in PowerShell remoting and WMI remoting. You should use PSExec if this is something you need to do!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.

OK I cannot.

The installation of PsExec is easy: "*Just copy PsExec onto your executable path. Typing "psexec" displays its usage syntax.*"
I can maybe deploy it first and then use it.

David: I'd like to open the browser to display an information to the user. (eg) To inform him that the process is over and redirect him.

Comment: In fact, you don't have to copy PSExec to all machines. If you point PSExec to a remote machine, it copies itself as a service

Comment: Absolutely I noticed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that which quiet I'm want to do:

> psexec -d "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"

IE Starts but the window is all black - I need the syntax to add -i [UserName/Pwd]

I also found that:
*Unfortunately, when you use a specific user account, PsExec passes credentials in the clear to the remote workstation, thus exposing the credentials to anyone who happens to be «listening in».*
Source: [PsExec Security -i](http://blog.isdecisions.com/post/13298789101/remoteexec-vs-psexec-not-is-the-same-league)

I also tried on a WM and there was a big graphical problem. (Win7)

Anyway even if I'm able to open a browser correctly, is there a way to open a specific URL ? If not I won't try further.

Source: [Windows Systernals PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553)

Answer (score 0):

psexec.exe \machinename -u DOMAIN\username -i -d "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplorer.exe" http://www.webpage.com

This will show up in the current shell of the user that is logged in.